# Downloading file, changing extension and merging into 1 file

Tags: php, fputs

Trying to download files via the URL, rename from the .ADM extension to .txt
then put contents of each file into a single txt file
However its saying the fputs param 2 is a resource
The $logfile['name'] is the filename thats stored in the array

Heres my code

```
foreach($items as $logfile)
 {
  $getfile = $logfile['Download'];
  $newfile = file_put_contents(str_replace('ADM','txt',$logfile['name']), 
 file_get_contents($getfile));
 $name = str_replace('ADM','txt',$logfile['name']);
 $newfile = $name;
 $file = fopen($newfile, 'rb');
 $output = fopen('tmp/test.txt', 'wb');
 fputs($output, $file);
 fclose($output);
 fclose($file);
}
```

Its downloading each and renaming however its not moving the content & giving me this error

```
 Warning: fputs() expects parameter 2 to be string, resource given in
```

Comment: In the call `fputs($output, $file)`, both `$output` and `$file` are the results of calling `fopen()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of `fputs` is the content of a file. Not a file resource.

Instead of

```
$file = fopen($newfile, 'rb');
```

You‘ll need to get the contents of the file

```
$content = file_get_contents($newfile);
```

Or, if you like to use `fopen`, you can use `fread`:

```
$file = fopen($newfile, 'rb');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($newfile));
```

Then you can put this content into another file:

```
fputs($output, $content);
```

Comment: Thank you .. once again my stupidity stopped me seeing the issui